# Getting Timed out Error in visual Studio while Developing a App in windows store app

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

Iam Getting This Error when i run the project in visual studio 2013,Iam develop a windows store app but my project is not run, i was updated my windows 8.1 to windows 10,And i develop a new project but same problem is occur any Solution please Thanks in Advance

[Check This Error Message link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5sr8.png)

Comment: It seems you can not build a windows 10 app in visual studio 2013, you have to bulid a windows 10 app in visual studio 2015.  See here
(https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners/UWP-001-Series-Introduction), from 0:08:40.

Comment: but my other friends developed Apps also in Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Windows 8.1 apps can be developed in Visual Studio 2013. For your question, I actually don't know how to help, but i konw if you want to develop UWP apps, you have to use Visual Studio 2015, and must use windows 10 to build a windows 10 app, and must choose a developer mode. Correct: In the video, it is declared at 0:02:25.

Comment: ok iam going to install VS 2015